# Finding heuristic and Identifying Traveling Salesman like algorithm (With some changes)

Tags: algorithm, path-finding, heuristics, traveling-salesman, motion-planning

I need a heuristic for the Traveling Salesman Problem with the below changes:

•   We need to visit only a subset of V (There is given a subset of V that we must visit). V=Cities.

•   We does not need to end the travel at the start vertex(city).

Is there a known name for this problem? That I'll be able to find a good heuristic to solve it?

Thanks advanced :)

Comment: Is there restrictions (Such as must path through each vertex not in V at most once?) If not, I think you can find all-to-all shortest paths, and reduce the problem to normal TSP on V, with modified edges weight according to all-to-all shortest paths.

Comment: Thanks Amit, sounds good, how do I address the other difference (We does not need to end the travel at the start vertex)? As I know TSP need to end it's travel at the start vertex, how do I avoid this? I just need to pass through all the "special" vertices (vertices in the subset) and stop there.